# emacs icicle dabbrev completion

Tags: emacs, emacs24, icicles

I would like to use dabbrev completion in icicles as mentioned in the following page.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completion_in_Other_Buffers

> If user option `icicle-top-level-key-bindings’ contains an entry for
>   ‘dabbrev-completion’ then Icicles remaps keys normally bound to
>   command ‘dabbrev-completion’ to command ‘icicle-dabbrev-completion’,
>   which uses Icicles completion whenever there are multiple completion
>   candidates. You can then use any Icicles features, such as apropos
>   completion and candidate cycling. In addition, you can complete an
>   empty prefix, starting from scratch with apropos completion.

However I don't understand how to set the 'icicle-top-level-key-bindings' in my .emacs file.
I tried a number of steps that didn't work.
'M-x describe-variable RET icicle-top-level-key-bindings' shows me a list with lot of options. How could I add ‘dabbrev-completion’ to this existing list.

I got the icicle library from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Libraries

I also see following code in [icicles-opt.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/icicles-opt.el)

```
 (dabbrev-completion icicle-dabbrev-completion
                     (< emacs-major-version 24))
```

Does it mean dabbrev mode is not supported in emacs2.4.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `M-x customize-option icicle-top-level-key-bindings` to customize this option.
2. Yes, I have not yet updated the code for `icicle-dabbrev-completion` to support Emacs 24. Use regular `dabbrev-completion` if you use Emacs 24.

Comment: Thanks Drew for the info on customize-option.
dabbrev-completion doesn't provide a menu of completions.
Pls update when emacs24 support is added for icicle-dabbrev

Comment: OK. It should be straightforward to do by copying the whole Emacs 24 definition of `dabbrev-completion` and modifying it.  I've been putting off updating it because I wanted to instead integrate the needed changes into a single, cross-versions definition, but maybe I won't bother with that.

Comment: @Rajendran -- I've updated Icicles now for this.  Please try the latest update (files `icicles-cmd1.el` and `icicles-opt.el`).